# Enumerating of JObject of NewtonSoft.Json loses '\' character in C#

Tags: json, json.net

I would like to parse json string using `JObject.Parse()` of **NewtonSoft.Json**. Assume that the json string is like this:

```
{"json":"{\"count\":\"123\"}"}
```

1. The result of `jObject.First.ToString()` is `"json": "{\"count\":\"123\"}"`.
2. The result of `jObject["json"].ToString()` is `{"count":"123"}`. Enumerating gets the same result as this.

The testing code I used is like this.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void JsonParseTest()
{
   var json = "{\"json\":\"{\\\"count\\\":\\\"123\\\"}\"}";
   var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
   Console.WriteLine($"json : {json}");
   Console.WriteLine($"jObject.First.ToString() : {jObject.First}");
   Console.WriteLine($"jObject[\"json\"].ToString() : {jObject["json"]}");
}
```

We can see that enumerating of jObject will lose the character **'\'**. What is the problem? I would be appreciated for any suggestion :)

**EDIT 1**
The version of NewtonSoft is 12.0.3 released in 2019.11.09.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parser isn't loosing anything. There is no literal `\` in your example. The backslashes are purely part of the JSON syntax to escape the `"` inside the string vlue. The value of the key `json` **is** `{"count":"123"}`.

If you want to have backslashes in that value (however I don't see why you would want that), then you need add them, just like you added them in your C# string (C# and JSON happen to have the same escaping mechanism):

```
{"json":"{\\\"count\\\":\\\"123\\\"}"}
```

with leads to the C# code:

```
var json = "{\"json\":\"{\\\\\\\"count\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"123\\\\\\\"}\"}";
```

Comment: Thank you for your pretty answer. : ) You are right that the json string of `{"count":"123"}` gets rid of backslashes when it get out of the origin json. It means that backslashes only have meaning when the json string is contained in the other json.

Comment: In my code, I would like to parse a json and reassemble it again. It loses the backslashes in new json. After this post, I convert the json string to a JValue to fix that. Thank you very much!